# Convert NVARCHAR DATE to DATETIME using CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar, ssms-2017

I am getting the following error when trying to convert nvarchar column to datetime.

```
Select *
from table 1
where
convert(datetime, col1) >= '2018-08-29 00:00:00.000'
```

Error message

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Col1 is an NVARCHAR column (I have no control over this data type so I cannot change it)

I have seen some examples of charindex but can't seem to get it to work, any help getting the code right for it to work is much appreciated.

UPDATE - '2018-08-29 00:00:00.000' is a datetime column which needs to stay that was in order to do the where clause.

Comment: could you give us a sample of the data that's not working? could well just be a formatting issue or a US vs Rest of the World data issue

Comment: That means there is at least one value in col1 that is not able to converted to a datetime. You can identify those rows easily by using try_convert. Then if at all possible stop storing dates in varchar.

Comment: Once sanitizing the wrong data you would need to consider checking what did insert that bad data to prevent it. You could add a trigger before insert or update to force an exception in case the data was not in the correct format (as a last option, triggers are nasty). Check Gordon's answer on how to detect the bad data.

Comment: You need to provide sample data showing us the format or check the source data for errors as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: There are no errors in the source format. The datatype is nvarchar compared to datetime as stated in my question. the date comes out like 24-Jul-2018 in the nvarchar column

Answer (score 2):

Use `try_convert()`:

```
Select *
from table 1
where try_convert(datetime, col1) >= '2018-08-29'  -- time is not necessary
```

To find the values that are causing a problem:

```
select col1
from t
where try_convert(datetime, col1) is null and col1 is not null;
```

Note:  You may need a format argument for the conversion.  In the end, though, you should fix your data to use the correct type for `col1`.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry but the format of the datetime cannot be changed, it is col1 that has to be changed.

Comment: @BeckyPurland . . . I am missing the point of your comment.  The only change I made to the constant was removing the time -- it seeps superfluous but you can leave it in.  The answer is about `col1`.

Comment: Try_convert doesn't work I'm afraid. I am looking for a way of using CHARINDEX. I think this will work but just can't figure out how to get it into my code as I haven't used this function before

Answer (score 0):

You can define `SET DATEFORMAT YMD` before the query start.
have a look of below query,

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD
Select *
from table 1
where
convert(datetime, col1) >= '2018-08-29 00:00:00.000'
```